# Word for disturbing the peace & normal conditions of an area or region for certain motives

Tags: word-choice

I need a proper word when someone or an army intentionally disturbs the peace and normal conditions of an area or region for certain motives.

Answer (score 1):

It's not super clear, but you might be looking for

> 1. [invasion](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/invasion?s=t)
>
>    1. an act or instance of invading or entering as an enemy, especially by an army.
> 2. [takeover](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/takeover)
>
>    1. the act of seizing, appropriating, or arrogating authority, control, management, etc.
> 3. [occupation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occupation)
>
>    2. **a** :  the possession, use, or settlement of land :  occupancy
>    3. **a** :  the act or process of taking possession of a place or area :  seizure
>         **b** :  the holding and control of an area by a foreign military force
>         **c** :  the military force occupying a country or the policies carried out by it

Answer (score 0):

**intrude, tamper, meddle** in the affairs of a nation

**derange, unbalance, disorganize** the order of a society

Put one of the above or other word into the search field of this web-site [www.thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/) and you'll likely find a fitting word.